# How can I get Munin to generate image source paths properly?

Tags: munin

I'm having trouble with Munin's comparison pages. All other pages work just fine. What happens is that the relative URLs it is generating for the `img` `src` parameters are wrong. In the snippet below you can see how the path to the HTML index page is preceded by `../../` and that works perfectly. But the `img` `src` path is only preceded by `../` and is broken. If I manually change the URL by prefixing an additional `../` then I can see the image just fine. It doesn't look like this is something that I can change in the templates. Any ideas?

```
<span class="nodetitle"><a href="SERVER_NAME/index.html">
            SERVER_NAME</a> :: 
                <a 
                  href="../../PATH/TO/SERVER_NAME/diskstats_iops/index.html">

                Disk IOs per device
                </a>
        </span><br />

            <a href="../../PATH/TO/SERVER_NAME/diskstats_iops/index.html">
                <img src="../PATH/TO/SERVER_NAME/diskstats_iops-day.png" alt="Disk IOs per device"
                class="i"

                 />
            </a>

        </div>
```

**Edit**: Munin version 2.0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently a bug, although I can't find a ticket or issue for it. The folks in the Munin IRC channel pointed me in this direction. My issue was fixed by upgrading to 2.0.12.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be present in 2.0.25 too, it seems `HTMLOld.pm` has still a bug at line 295

```
$node->{$imgsrc} =~ s|^\.\./\.\./(?:\.\./)?|../|;
```

needs to be

```
$node->{$imgsrc} =~ s|^\.\./(?:\.\./)?|../|;
```

somehow related: [munin ticket 769](http://munin-monitoring.org/ticket/769)